# Is there a maximum concurrency for AWS s3 multipart uploads?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload, concurrency

[Referring to the docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/service-s3.html), you can specify the number of concurrent connection when pushing large files to Amazon Web Services s3 using the multipart uploader. While it does say the concurrency defaults to 5, it does not specify a maximum, or whether or not the size of each chunk is derived from the total filesize / concurrency.

I trolled the source code and the comment is pretty much the same as the docs:

> Set the concurrency level to use when uploading parts. This affects
>   how many parts are uploaded in parallel. You must use a local file as
>   your data source when using a concurrency greater than 1

So my functional build looks like this (the vars are defined by the way, this is just condensed for example):

```
use Aws\Common\Exception\MultipartUploadException;
use Aws\S3\Model\MultipartUpload\UploadBuilder;

    $uploader = UploadBuilder::newInstance()
      ->setClient($client)
      ->setSource($file)
      ->setBucket($bucket)
      ->setKey($file)
      ->setConcurrency(30)
      ->setOption('CacheControl', 'max-age=3600')
      ->build();
```

Works great except a 200mb file takes 9 minutes to upload... with 30 concurrent connections? Seems suspicious to me, so I upped concurrency to 100 and the upload time was 8.5 minutes. Such a small difference could just be connection and not code.

So my question is whether or not there's a concurrency maximum, what it is, and if you can specify the size of the chunks or if chunk size is automatically calculated. My goal is to try to get a 500mb file to transfer to AWS s3 within 5 minutes, however I have to optimize that if possible.

Comment: 200MB × 8 (bits/byte) ÷ 9 (minutes) ÷ 60 (sec/min) ≅ 3 megabits per second... which looks, to me, like a Suspiciously Round Number... could that be the limit of your upload connection speed?  S3 is certainly capable of accepting multipart uploads much faster than this, but the [S3 API itself imposes a minimum size limit of 5MB/part](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/qfacts.html) (except the last part, of course), so a 200MB file couldn't possibly be uploaded in any more than 40 parts, regardless of any hard concurrency cap in the php-sdk code (if there is one).

Comment: Connection speed is a good theory but I run them on a business connection and a standard home for testing expected connections in real life. I rummaged through the code some more and it looks like max is 10,000 but I wonder if that's more like 10,000 maximum concurrent bucket hits and not specific to this single push. Upping to 1,000 seemed to bring me down to 7.5 minutes... still working it out though. Not convinced yet

Comment: Have you looked at your CPU utilization during the upload?  There's another potential choke point.

Comment: Yup. It infrequently gets as high as 52% or so for that one task, but mostly remains pretty calm at about 7%. Idle is fairly consistent ~75% range. I've been running cases all day using varying concurrence and setMinPartSize - assuming that is size per chunk - and in all cases the time varies only minimally. Good thing is it is working, so maybe that's just the limitation I have to deal with

Comment: S3 itself definitely would not be the bottleneck -- using my own hand-rolled S3 multipart uploader, I routinely see 45 Mbit/sec uploads from my office in Ohio to s3-us-west-2 in Oregon (75ms RTT) with only 8 concurrent parts.

Comment: Do you have any specific settings? I had suspected concurrence wouldn't need to be set any, or much higher than the 5 default. Maybe there's something else I am not factoring. Ex: I tried ->setMinPartSize(8388608) but default is 5 megs and I didn't see a difference outside the standard minute or so variance. And I have yet to throw it up on the live server. Using the dev environments could also be the culprit.

Comment: Just ran it on an actual server with real connection power and got a 109mb file to upload in 23 seconds using `->setConcurrency(100)->setMinPartSize(10485760)` (10 megs) - still not positive there's some magic setting, but this is good for now. Thanks for your input

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking through the source code, it looks like 10,000 is the maximum concurrent connections. There is no automatic calculations of chunk sizes based on concurrent connections but you could set those yourself if needed for whatever reason.

I set the chunk size to 10 megs, 20 concurrent connections and it seems to work fine. On a real server I got a 100 meg file to transfer in 23 seconds. Much better than the 3 1/2 to 4 minute it was getting in the dev environments. Interesting, but thems the stats, should anyone else come across this same issue.

This is what my builder ended up being:

```
$uploader = UploadBuilder::newInstance()
  ->setClient($client)
  ->setSource($file)
  ->setBucket($bicket)
  ->setKey($file)
  ->setConcurrency(20)
  ->setMinPartSize(10485760)
  ->setOption('CacheControl', 'max-age=3600')
  ->build();
```

I may need to up that max cache but as of yet this works acceptably. The key was moving the processor code to the server and not relying on the weakness of my dev environments, no matter how powerful the machine is or high class the internet connection is.

Answer (score 0):

We can abort the process during upload and can halt all the operations and abort the upload at any instance. We can set Concurrency and minimum part size.

```
$uploader = UploadBuilder::newInstance()
->setClient($client)
->setSource('/path/to/large/file.mov')
->setBucket('mybucket')
->setKey('my-object-key')
->setConcurrency(3)
->setMinPartSize(10485760)
->setOption('CacheControl', 'max-age=3600')
->build();

try {
$uploader->upload();
echo "Upload complete.\n";
} catch (MultipartUploadException $e) {
$uploader->abort();
echo "Upload failed.\n";
}
```